# Dockerfile 403 authenticationrequired during apt-get

Tags: linux, windows, docker, dockerfile

I'm on Windows 10 with Docker Desktop. I have a simple Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm

### Installing dependencies for the PHP modules
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip
```

I keep getting `403 authenticationrequired` error during the `apt-get update and install`. My colleague in the same network is building the file just fine. I tried using WSL with Ubuntu, turning my company proxy on and off, deleting the SSL_CERT_FILE environement variable (I don't know why, I'm trying everything).

Does anyone has an idea what's causing this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by `turning my company proxy on and off` where? Please update the question. Try to setup proxy on Docker Desktop -> Settings  -> Resources -> Proxies

Comment: @Max I thought it was a proxy thing, I already tried setting it up in Docker Desktop, even in the Dockerfile, not working.